# Ruby: Mapping a Hash

Tags: ruby

In Python, I can create a test hash with list comprehension that I check against a suite of test(s). How can I achieve the same thing in ruby? (I'm running on ruby 1.9.3)

**Python:**

```
test = {x: self.investor.annual_return(x) for x in xrange(1, 6)}
```

**Ruby (attempt):**

```
test = Hash[(1..5).map { |x| [x, @investor.annual_return(x)] }]
```

Comment: So you want to map 1 through 6 to `self.investor.annual_return(1)` through `self.investor.annual_return(6)` as `{1 => self.investor.annual_return(1), 2 => self.investor.annual_return(2)...`?

Comment: annual_return pulls out an value of an array that calculates a compounding interest value. In this case, I'm mapping a hash to create this without actually having to type out: 1 => 10720.00, 2 => 11491.84, 3 =>12319.25, 4 =>13206.24, 5 => 14517.09

Comment: Then @ennuikiller is the answer you want. I had to look up list comprehension, but it looks like the definition in Wikipedia includes a "predicate clause" that I don't see in your example. As in "iterate 1 through 5 and make the number the key and the return of the function of that number the value, BUT only if some predicate clause is also true" their python example is: `S = [2 * x for x in range(101) if x ** 2 > 3]` and their Ruby example is: `(1..100).select{|x| x ** 2 > 3 }.collect{|x| 2 * x}`

Comment: Yes, your current answer and @ennuikiller's answers are the same. I would hazard the opinion that Rubyists would create the hash his way rather than yours. But seeing your way, I actually prefer it. I would like to hear from the hardcore Rubyists why either way is better, as his way is the only way I've really seen used so far in my learning of Ruby.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. I'll keep at it, and consider what you've said. That implementation seems to make all of my tests(s) pass and to be safe, I made sure the hash printed the expected result which was: ```{1=>10720.0, 2=>11491.84, 3=>12319.25, 4=>13206.24, 5=>14157.09}```

Comment: I should clarify, I like the use of `Hash[...` though it seems un-Ruby. But I do prefer the format of ennuikiller's block because it is easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You often see:

```
test = (1..5).reduce({}) {|h, x| h[x] = @investor.annual_return(x); h}
```

but (since Ruby 1.9) many prefer [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
test = (1..5).each_with_object({}) {|x, h| h[x] = @investor.annual_return(x)}
```

in part because there is no need to return the object `h` to the iterator, as there is with [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`).

Comment: God, that's much more readable. I tried it with reduce the first go around but couldn't get the syntax right. I just get confused with the backwards deal with ```|x,h| h[x].```

Answer (score 2):

You want something like:

```
test = {}
(1..5).map { |i| test[i] = @investor.annual_return(i) }
```

Comment: I've been noodling around with it, I came up with a proper solution just now. It's a little tricky because Ruby doesn't have the same kind of setup as Python's Dict comprehension. What do you think of my implementation?

Comment: Don't use `map` for this, use `each`. While `map` will iterate over the range like `each`, it's going to try to return an array of all generated values assigned to `test[i]` as it iterates, which wastes CPU time. `each` is a simple iterator and won't return an array so it's more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I think your Ruby code is fine, depending on what version of Ruby you're running.

Starting with:

```
class Investor
  def annual_return(i)
    i * i
  end
end

investor = Investor.new
```

In Ruby 1.9+, this will work:

```
test = Hash[ (1..5).map { |x| [x, investor.annual_return(x)] } ]
test # => {1=>1, 2=>4, 3=>9, 4=>16, 5=>25}
```

However, prior to 1.9, Hash wouldn't convert an array of arrays containing key/value pairs, so we had to get a bit fancier, and `flatten` the nested elements into a single array, then "explode" those elements for Hash:

```
test = Hash[ *(1..5).map { |x| [x, investor.annual_return(x)] }.flatten ]
test # => {1=>1, 2=>4, 3=>9, 4=>16, 5=>25}
```

The result is the same, it's just less hassle these days.

And, just to show what Ruby does as we build a hash this way:

```
(1..5).map { |x| [x, investor.annual_return(x)] }
# => [[1, 1], [2, 4], [3, 9], [4, 16], [5, 25]]

(1..5).map { |x| [x, investor.annual_return(x)] }.flatten
# => [1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25]
```

Comment: I see, I appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you could try this:

```
{}.tap { |x| (1..5).each do |y| x[y] = @investor.annual_return(i) end }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with:

```
(1..5).map { |x| [x, @investor.annual_return(x)] }.to_h
```

(Doc: [`Array#to_h`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h))

`Hash[*array]` is used to construct a hash from a flat array (`[key1, value1, key2, value2, keyN, valueN]`), whereas `Array#to_h` is used to construct a hash from an array of key-value pairs (`[ [key1, value1], [key2, value2], [keyN, valueN] ]`).